# How can I list all open windows on Mac from a Python script?

Tags: python, macos, user-interface

I'd like to be able to grab a list of all windows that are open on macOS/OS X from a Python script. This would be the Mac equivalent on win32's [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) API call.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use this to get a list of the title/caption text of every open window along with position/size information.

Is there an OS or Cocoa API call that will return this info?

Comment: I don't own a Mac to test. But google came up with these API's.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pyobjc](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/). This should get the title names for you:

```
from AppKit import NSWorkspace
[apps["NSApplicationName"] for apps in NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().launchedApplications()]
```

---

A little more background: `pyobjc` is implemented using [Quartz Window Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services?language=objc), which is the program they used to manage application windows on Mac OS.

Comment: as you are giving the only answer atm you should keep in mind to provide a bit more context to boast your answer quality. This helps to prevent down-voting or bot labeling with "low quality" answer. Quality improvements are for example explain the essentials of pyobj here with text and/or images. End of Review. Welcome and enjoy SO ;-)